# What is "exclusive neighborhoods"?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to read a proof but don't understand what does this mean. Thank you very much!

So here is the question I am trying to prove: "Show that for a Lefschetz map f on a compact manifold X, there can be only ﬁnitely many ﬁxed points." And the proof is: "The graph of f is transversal to the diagonal inside X×X." Then I get lost here: "Now we take the preimage of the diagonal under the graph map from X to X×X. This is a 0-manifold inside X, and being a manifold can’t have limit points."

And "exclusive neighborhoods" appears in the followed proof:

Then (a) we can put an open set around each one containing no others, (b) the union of them is a closed set. Take the following list of open sets: the *exclusive neighborhoods*, plus the complement of the set of ﬁxed points. This is an open cover of X, so by compactness it has a ﬁnite subcover, so there must have been ﬁnitely many of them. QED.

Comment: A whole lot more context would be helpful. What is it a proof *of*? Are you reading this in a book, a journal article, etc.? If so, which one?

Comment: It means that only rich people are allowed to live there.

Comment: Hi @ZevChonoles, thank you! So here is the question I am trying to prove: "Show that for a Lefschetz map f on a compact manifold X, there can be only ﬁnitely
many ﬁxed points." And the proof is: "The graph of f is transversal to the diagonal inside $X \times X$." Then I get lost here: "Now we take the preimage of the diagonal under the graph map from $X$ to $X \times X$. This is a 0-manifold inside X, and being a manifold can’t have limit points."

Comment: Then the proof continues as follows: Then (a) we can put an open set around each one containing no others, (b) the union of them is a closed set.
Take the following list of open sets: the exclusive neighborhoods, plus the complement
of the set of ﬁxed points. This is an open cover of X, so by compactness it has a ﬁnite
subcover, so there must have been
ﬁnitely many of them. QED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess two neighbourhoods $M$ and $N$ with $M\cap N=\emptyset$.

Comment: Oh, I think that makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: We really need the context, since the term is not standard, and what you describe are normally called *disjoint* nbhds.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hi Brian, thanks for your comment! I added more details in the description.

Comment: @MathSnail: With that addition I think that par’s answer is indeed correct.

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott. But could you help me with "Now we take the preimage of the diagonal under the graph map from X to X×X. This is a 0-manifold inside X, and being a manifold can’t have limit points." I couldn't follow why this is a 0-manifold inside X.

Comment: @MathSnail: I can’t help much: I know little about manifolds, I’ve no idea what a Lefschetz map is, and a little Googling tells me that *transversal* has a technical sense here with which I’m unfamiliar. My best guess is that they’re taking $f^{-1}[\Delta]$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal in $X\times X$, and saying that because $f$ is transversal to $\Delta$, this inverse image is a $0$-manifold. I do know that a $0$-manifold is a space with the discrete topology, which of course has no limit points.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8977/discussion-between-mathsnail-and-brian-m-scott)

Comment: Oh I got it!! Thank you so much @BrianM.Scott!

Comment: @MathSnail: Great! You’re welcome.